# ArrayList lastIndexof

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors, iterator, lastindexof

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class bracketMatch {

    public bracketMatch() {
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter seq");
    String[] seq = scan.nextLine().split("");
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    int x = 0;
    String check = null;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(seq));   
        for(String brak : seq)
        {
            switch(brak)
            {
                case "(":
                    temp.add("(");

                    break;
                case "[":
                    temp.add("[");

                    break;
                case "{":
                    temp.add("{");

                    break;
                case "<":
                    temp.add("<");

                    break;
                case ")":
                    temp.add( ")");

                    break;
                case "]":
                    temp.add("]");

                    break;
                case "}":
                    temp.add("}");

                    break;
                case ">":
                    temp.add(">");

                    break;


            }

        }


                      x =  temp.lastIndexOf("(");
                        System.out.println( x);
                   /*  if(x != -1)
                     {  
                        temp.remove(check);
                        temp.remove(x);

                        }*/


                      System.out.println(temp.toString()) ;

    }

}
```

The above code is for matchingbrackets, but I stumbled upon `ArrayList` method `lastIndexOf`.
However, it is not fetching the correct index and is working like `indexOf` method.

Should I use stack or `linkedlist` instead of `ArrayList`?

Also, any help on iterating an arraylist and removing its element, since iterator and foreach gives error.

Comment: Hello, could you give an example of what you code should do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give us some more information? Method lastIndexOf works properly, it gives you last occurence of object in list, it doesn't work like indexOf. If you want to delete last occurence of "(" from arraylist just uncomment your temp.remove(x) line.

Comment: Happy to help. 
If it did, mark question as resolved, there is a chance someone will be doing similar thing and can find this question.